# Why do my Isolated mode Azure functions not run in parallel?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-isolated

My function app is Isolated mode B1

It contains http and queue triggered functions

The app only processes one request at a time and others wait for the previous to finish. This includes http requests made in parallel and queue triggers when the queues are all full.

I see that I can scale my app out to 2 instances, but is this really required to handle simultaneous requests?

Example Http function that takes 60 seconds to handle two concurrent calls:

```
 [Function("TestConcurrency")]
 public HttpResponseData Concurrency([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
 {
     var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     response.WriteString("Concurrency");
     response.WriteString(DateTime.Now.ToString());
     Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
     response.WriteString(DateTime.Now.ToString());
     return response;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for app setting FUNCTIONS_WORKER_PROCESS_COUNT which has default 1

Async-await also frees up threads but starting with only 1 was my main problem